# Bash : commands executed when echoing on remote server over SSH

Tags: bash, variables, ssh, echo

**EDIT:**
I just solved it by using `echo $(printf '%q' "$content")` instead of `echo -e "$content"`. I don't understand why I have to do this to print it on the remote server but it's not needed in local.

---

I want to print the content of a bash variable (multi-line string containing some shell commands) on a remote server using SSH.

When I print it on the local server (line 21 : `echo "$content"`), the output is correct.
When I print it on the remote one (line 37 : `echo -e "$content"`), the double-quote are gone and the commands are executed (`$(date)` for instance).

I don't understand what's wrong. Can anyone help me, please?

**Script :**

```
#!/bin/bash

serv05=( serv05.company.org myUser )
serv06=( serv06.company.org myUser )
serv07=( serv07.company.org myUser )
serv08=( serv08.company.org myUser )

list_env=( serv05 serv06 serv07 serv08 )

read -r -d '' content << 'TEST'
#!/bin/bash

# USAGE :
# "./change_date.sh 24" : 24/09/2014
# "./change_date.sh 25" : 25/09/2014
# "./change_date.sh" : 24/09/2014

echo "Before : " $(date)
TEST

echo "$content"
echo
echo

for i in "${list_env[@]}"; do
    serv="${i}[0]"
    user="${i}[1]"
    all="${i}[@]"

    echo "## BEGIN SERV ## (${i} : ${!serv}) ##"

    ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o LogLevel=quiet -T ${!user}@${!serv} << EOF
        printf '\033[0;32m' # Green text color
        echo \$HOSTNAME : $(whoami)
        sudo su -
        whoami
        echo -e "$content"
        printf '\033[0m' # Standard text color
EOF

    echo "##  END SERV  ## (${i} : ${!serv}) ##"
    echo
done
```

**Output:**

```
admin@myServ> ./test.sh
#!/bin/bash

# USAGE :
# "./change_date.sh 24" : 24/09/2014
# "./change_date.sh 25" : 25/09/2014
# "./change_date.sh" : 24/09/2014

echo "Before : " $(date)


## BEGIN SERV ## (serv05 : serv05.company.org) ##
serv05 : myUser
root
#!/bin/bash

# USAGE :
# ./change_date.sh 24 : 24/09/2014
# ./change_date.sh 25 : 25/09/2014
# ./change_date.sh : 24/09/2014

echo Before :  Thu Sep 25 12:59:13 CEST 2014
##  END SERV  ## (serv05 : serv05.company.org) ##

[...]

admin@myServ>
```

Comment: Sidenote : Check what shell the target environment is using. `echo -e` is bashism and by default `echo` in posix compliant shells is `echo -e`

Comment: Why are you adding {}? Those brackets are for execution. You can read about it on `man bash`

Comment: can you add escape characters to the double quote and to the $ as you do it for the hostname and check

Comment: I just solved it with `echo $(printf '%q' "$content")`. I don't understand why I have to do that on the remote but not on the local one.